# How to translate "wrong password" message

Tags: login

I try to translate the "wrong password" response at system log in.

I update wp-login.php, however I do not find there any handler for wrong password, wrong user.

Maybe such generic tests are handled somewhere else?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to translate "ERROR: Invalid username. Lost your password?"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127702/how-to-translate-error-invalid-username-lost-your-password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also use the filter `wp_login_errors` available in `wp-login.php` to do the above. Using the same filter you can customize other error messages too like `registration`, `checkmail` etc.

Use the below code in the active theme's **`functions.php`** file

```
add_filter( 'wp_login_errors', 'override_incorrect_password_msg', 10, 2 );
function override_incorrect_password_msg( $errors, $redirect_to ) {
    if( isset( $errors->errors['incorrect_password'] ) ) {
        $errors->errors['incorrect_password'][0] = 'Your new message';
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

And if you want to get hold of the username at this time you can do that by using another hook ie: **`wp_login_failed`**

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'wpse_end_login_fail' );
function wpse_end_login_fail( $username ) {

echo $username;
// Go on with what you want to do with the login failed username

}
```

The above will give you the username

You can see the above set of codes in action in the below image. You can see the username we got using the hook in the top left corner of the image/screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I assume a relavant handler is due in the case of "unknown user"?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by unknown user?

Comment: Whats your requirement here, wasn't it to customize the wordpress incorrect password message? Wordpress checks if username and password matches else the message. Do you want to point out if the username is invalid itself!!

Comment: Yes, exactly; I want to trap the handler of inexistent username.

Comment: @p.a. I have edited the answer, now with the second function you can  get the username when the login fails ie:the username  is correct but the password is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The text comes from `wp_authenticate_username_password()` in `wp-includes/user.php`. There is no other filter than `gettext`. So this works:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translation, $text, $domain )
{
    if ( 'default' !== $domain )
        return $translation;

    if ( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the username <strong>%1$s</strong> is incorrect. <a href="%2$s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>?' !== $text )
        return $translation;

    return 'Custom password message';
}, 10, 3 );
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Thank you. I assume a relavant handler is due in the case of "unknown user"?