# How to translate "ERROR: Invalid username. Lost your password?"

Tags: username

I want to translate the above message which appears on invalid username.

I know the answer is very similar to the one proposed [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126620/how-to-translate-wrong-password-message) by I cannot find the exact handler.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the en_GB version of the .mo translation file, this string is available:

```
<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username. <a href=\"%s\" title=\"Password Lost and Found\">Lost your password</a>?
```

and the reference is from wp-includes/user.php on line 93. I found this using [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) and searching using Ctrl + F.

From line 93 we get the following code:

```
return new WP_Error( 'invalid_username', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username. <a href="%s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>?' ), wp_lostpassword_url() ) );
```

Which means you should write a function for your functions.php hooking into `invalid_username` like so:

```
add_filter( 'wp_login_errors', 'override_incorrect_username_message', 10, 2 );
function override_incorrect_username_message( $errors, $redirect_to ) {
    if( isset( $errors->errors['invalid_username'] ) ) {
        $errors->errors['invalid_username'][0] = 'Your new translated message';
    }

    return $errors;
 }
```

You can hunt around in wp-includes.php for other similar error messages which you can fix in a similar way.

Comment: many thanks for your answer, unfortunately it does nothing in my case.. I still search it, thank you.

Comment: I also try to add the message in my theme's .mo file but to no avail.

Comment: I found a typo in your answer. Correcting it above. It now works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops! Yeah. Thanks for that. An oversight on my part. Glad it works.